# Не открывает js файлы

Tags: javascript, html, файлы, visual-studio-code

[image]

При попытке открыть `javaScript` файл выходит подобная ошибка (*правый нижний угол картинки*).

А в браузере, сообщается, что файл не найден или удален.

До этого удалял `VS Code` и менял папку с файлами ( **туда же перебросил `VS Code`** )

Answer (score 1):

Укажите относительный путь так, если MyCode является основной директорией проекта(в данном случае папка, где находится html-страница):

```
<script src="js/newCode.js"></script>
```